# MS SQL Server Trigger after another trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I would like to create trigger in MS SQL Server that would be call after finishing another trigger. This trigger that is called first is insert trigger. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.

But the tricky part is to track the order they are executed. It is strongly advised to use multiple triggers of the same type **only if they are fully independent** and hence could be executed in any order. In your case, better use multiple stored procedure calls in single trigger. You'll thank yourself later.

For more information on the subject, see previous question in SO:
[SQL Server triggers - order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94103/sql-server-triggers-order-of-execution)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can do nesting of trigger up to 32 level.
If you want more nesting then you can use CTE (about 100 level of nesting).