# Update triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

If I have a statement like below.

```
Update table emp set sal=10 where 1=2
```

And I have applied all the four triggers:

- Before,
- after,
- statement level,
- row level

So which triggers will be fired?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you test it?

```
SQL> create table test as select empno, sal from emp where deptno = 10;

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bu_r
  2    before update on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    dbms_output.put_line('Before row');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_au_r
  2    after update on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    dbms_output.put_line('After row');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bu_s
  2    before update on test
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('Before statement');
  5  end;
  6  /

Trigger created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_au_s
  2    after update on test
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('After statement');
  5  end;
  6  /

Trigger created.
```

---

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> update test set sal = 10 where 1 = 2;
Before statement
After statement

0 rows updated.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

> which triggers will be fired?

All of the relevant triggers will fire, unless one throws an exception and terminates the update. Your statement will update zero rows (because of the `1=2` filter). The *statement* still executes, so the statement-level triggers will fire; but as no rows are affected, the row-level triggers will not fire.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-E76C8044-6942-4573-B7DB-3502FB96CF6F):

> A simple DML trigger fires at exactly one of these timing points:
>
> - Before the triggering statement runs ...
> - After the triggering statement runs ...
> - Before each row that the triggering statement affects ...
> - After each row that the triggering statement affects ...

Notice the "each row that the triggering statement affects" part for the row-level triggers. If the triggering statement doesn't affect any rows, they will not fire.

The *order* that they fire is also important, and that is shown [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-2585112C-C48F-40ED-B825-21DF975EA126) too:

> If two or more triggers with different timing points are defined for the same statement on the same table, then they fire in this order:
>
> 1. All `BEFORE STATEMENT` triggers
> 2. All `BEFORE EACH ROW` triggers
> 3. All `AFTER EACH ROW` triggers
> 4. All `AFTER STATEMENT` triggers

You can [see that in action](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=79d20cff806c718bcd67b92332cda9e7), using a modified version of @Littlefoot's code, with updates of zero rows, a single row and then multiple rows.

There is further advice in the documentation that goes a bit beyond your specific question, but which you might find relevant or useful at some point:

> If it is practical, replace the set of individual triggers with different timing points with a single compound trigger that explicitly codes the actions in the order you intend. For information about compound triggers, see "[Compound DML Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-8A0DA171-BE6A-4798-A1A4-677B88EA16A0)".
>
> If you are creating two or more triggers with the same timing point, and the order in which they fire is important, then you can control their firing order using the `FOLLOWS` and `PRECEDES` clauses (see "[FOLLOWS | PRECEDES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B__CIHDEBEI)").

Answer (score -1):

You can use sp_settriggerorder to define the order of each trigger on a table.
[SQL Server triggers - order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94103/sql-server-triggers-order-of-execution)

Comment: The question is about Oracle, not SQL Server.